# Azure AD Sync - Not updating the usagelocation from AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, synchronization, azure-active-directory

I have ADsync on a dc and I am trying to get it to pull the usagelocation from a users attributes, but it fails to populate, I have added the locale GB to msExchUsageLocation and also added a rule to the synchronization rules editor to obtain this information from the attribute and point it at the usagelocation, but still it shows blank. The only way to update the Usagelocation is to user the following ps script ;

```
Set-MsolUser -userprincipalname -User@domain.com -UsageLocation GB
```

I have a script that updates each users ad profile using  csv, and wanted to incorporate the usagelocation in that, however as it stands, the ps script is the only way to update this.

Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD's usageLocation syncs with On-prem AD's msExchUsageLocation by default.  You can populate that attribute on prem and it'll sync up.  Use two letter country codes in AD and Azure will translate them when you look at the user's profile.